# How do I constrain the "content" of a 9 patch image drawable?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to integrate Google sign-in in my App and I downloaded the assets([provided by Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines)) for creating a custom sign-in Google button. These files, I have found them to be 9 patch drawables.

So, a button I want to use from the files is like this:

[image]

You can see the patch lines here. My understanding from these is that the image can be stretched to right as well as bottom.

Now, my requirement is that of a button like above but stretched out horizontally with the Google icon constrained to the left. I set the above image as a drawable background for the button with `match_parent` width. The resulting button has the Google logo in the center of the button.

Is there any way, I can constrain this icon to the left while the rest of the Button stretches like its currently?

Answer (score 0):

you should remove top right line from your file, so your image would not be stretched to right and Google logo will not be centered horizontally. read more about 9patch [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html).